# how to set 3 lower bits of uint8_t in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I would like to set the 3 lower bites of uint8_t with value 3.
I've tried the following:

```
uint8_t temp = some_value;
temp = temp & 0x3
```

but this does not work....

Comment: temp = (temp & ~0x7) | 0x3;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set bits you need `|`:

```
temp = temp | 0x3;
```

or more compactly:

```
temp |= 0x3;
```

If you want to set a 3-bit span to the number 3, you need to both set and clear bits:

```
temp &= ~0x7; // clear bits
temp |= 0x3;  // set bits
```

Comment: If you think there's an error, please either correct it or point it out.

Comment: It's corrected already. I felt you meant the right thing, didn't think of editing, my brain is not the smartest sometimes.

Comment: when I use a variable with `uint8_t` type as a pointer and pass it to a function and try to use `temp = temp | 0x3;` in that function, VS give me an error that `expression must have integral type`! but `uint8_t` is 8bit integer, right?

Comment: @Bear Sounds like you're forgetting to dereference your pointer. Should be *temp = *temp | 0x3;

Comment: I was wondering, if you can do it without clean bits first. Something like copy paste  but I dont think there is a way for this.

Answer (score 3):

To set the three lower bits you need to set the mask `0x07`, because 7 represented in binary is `00000111`.

If you want to get a mask of lower bits by specifying the number of bits, you can use this formula:

```
int bits = 3; // 3 lower bits
uint8_t mask = (1 << bits) - 1; // 7
```

To clear the pre-existing value of those bits, use a negative of the mask with the bitwise operator "and":

```
temp = temp & ~mask; //  mask is 00000111
                     // ~mask is 11111000 (negative)
                     // this operation zero out the 3 last bits of temp
```

And then you assign a new value to those bits with the bitwise operator "or":

```
temp = temp | (new_value & mask); // applying mask to new_value to make
                                  // sure its within the bit limit
```

Answer (score 2):

`& 3` is logical and, it will clear all bits except two lowest. You want to or also.

So to set three lowest bits to three, you would use `temp = (temp & ~7) | 3`. ~ is a logical not, which turns 7 into "all other bits than the last three", which when used with and will clear the three bits. After that or the 3 into it.

Answer (score 1):

This will change the 3 lower bits of `z` to `011` (3), while preserving the upper 5 bits:

```
uint8_t z = something();
z = (z & ~7) | 3;
```

After this, the bits of `z` will look like this, where `x` means "unknown":

```
xxxxx011
```

Comment: 3 is `011` but since you're using a bit-wise `OR`, you don't know the result of the 3rd bit, so the result should be more like `xxxx xx11`

Comment: That bit was cleared by the & ~7